# issue appears only in generated app.exe and dont appear in the sources' execution | PowerBuilder

Tags: exe, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have an issue when i execute my app.exe, there is an error which is revealed only in the ".exe", if i try todo the same thing when i use the sources, there is no problem, i think the problem is when there is a call of the update method from a datastore, it return -1 with generated .exe and 0 when i execute sources.

i have tried to refresh any library from my app, before building, but the issue remains, for information the app is using a DB2 DATABASE, and it is built and run in a windows7 environment.

Answer (score 1):

The likely cause is that when you built the exe, the DataWindow object assigned to the DataStore wasn't included. You need to use a .pbr file in the Project object. Look in the help file under 'deploying your application'.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem as well when I deployed strictly to a *.exe file. The problem went away when I deployed to a *.exe with a *.pbd. This is established on the "libraries" tab of your project by checking the pbd checkbox.

An 'exe' only deployment can't handle hard coded 'literal strings' in your code. Creating and deploying 'pbd' library will allow 'literal strings'.